# They are the global leaders in the synthetic drug(s) industry

Tags: grammatical-number

They are the global leaders in the synthetic drug(s) industry.

Should the word 'drug(s)' be singular or plural in this sentence?

Answer (score 3):

To ask whether it "should" be the one or the other is to suggest that one of them is wrong.  Usage "in the wild" is our criterion for making such judgments, and both are used, **synthetic drug** and **synthetic drugs**, as modifiers of nouns like **industry** and **manufacturer**.

Compare "organic food producer" and "organic foods producer".

Answer (score -2):

I think the plural "drugs" is right because there might be various types of synthetic drugs available.